# Mysql PHP query. How do you "order by" two different columns in the database together?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 columns in my database. One is named "name01" and the other is named "name02". This database displays friends on my app. When I go to my friends list on the app I want all my friends displayed by name in asc order. The problem is users names could be in "name01" or "name02" depending on who sent the friend request first. How would you "order by" both name01 & name02 at the same time? I have tried doing it with a comma (ORDER BY name01, name02) but it orders one first and then the other so the names aren't all in alphabetical order.

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id01 = '$id' AND status01 = '1' OR id02 = '$id' AND status02 = '1' **ORDER BY name01, name02** Limit 500");
```

Above will order name01 separately from name02.

Comment: You could [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) the two names together and order by that value. Though that would potentially be really slow.

Comment: When username is in one of the fields, what does the other contain? Is it `NULL` or something else?

Comment: Also, please note that the way you're building your query is unsafe.
You're open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function and then ordering:

```
SELECT friends.*, GREATEST(IFNULL(name01, 0), IFNULL(name02, 0)) as greatest_name 
FROM friends 
WHERE id01 = '$id' AND status01 = '1' OR id02 = '$id' AND status02 = '1'
ORDER BY greatest_name Limit 500
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if any of the names are `NULL`, as the docs state `GREATEST() returns NULL if any argument is NULL`.

Comment: @El_Vanja Then we may use `GREATEST(IFNULL(name01, 0), IFNULL(name02, 0))`

Comment: I'd incorporate that into the answer. Someone might just skim over the comments and not notice.

Comment: Also, since the name is a string, use `''` rather than `0` (the integer zero "wins" against a string).

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you guys.